# Is it recommended to free pointer input object in C functions?

Tags: c

Let's say I have a function like the following

```
int some_func(int *input_array, int input_constant)
{
  int *output_array = malloc(input_constant * sizeof(int));

  /*...some operations that uses 'input_array'... */

  return output_array;
  free(output_array);
  free(input_array);
}
```

Above, we have a pointer object that is passed into the function. During the compilation stage, I do not get any error when I freed the pointer object that are like the example above. So, I assumed it is okay...? But I am not sure if this is a recommended practice in C. Is it necessary to `free` this pointer object in order to prevent any memory leak?

**Edit.**

Okay, To be more specific I am trying to create a function that generates a sub-array of an larger array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


float *sub_region(float *in_fld, int in_fld_nx, int in_fld_ny, int in_sub_nx, int in_sub_ny, int in_sub_num);


int main()
{
   int   i,j,k;
   int   x_siz = 12,
         y_siz = 12,
         sub_region_x_siz = 3,
         sub_region_y_siz = 6,
         sub_region_siz   = x_siz/sub_region_x_siz * y_siz/sub_region_y_siz;
   float *arr = malloc(sizeof(float) * x_siz * y_siz),
         *sub = malloc(sizeof(float) * sub_region_x_siz * sub_region_y_siz);

   printf("orig array\n");
   for (j=0;j<y_siz;j++)
   {
      for (i=0;i<x_siz;i++)
      {
         arr[j * x_siz + i] = j * x_siz + i;
         //printf("%3d  %3.1f\n",j * x_size + i, arr[j * x_size + i]);
         printf("%3d  ",j * x_siz + i);
      }
   printf("\n");

   }

   for (k=0;k<sub_region_siz;k++)
   {
      sub = sub_region((float*)arr, x_siz, y_siz, sub_region_x_siz, sub_region_y_siz, k);


      printf("\n\nsub area : %d \n\n",k);
      for (j=0;j<sub_region_y_siz;j++)
      {
         for (i=0;i<sub_region_x_siz;i++)
         {
            printf("%3.0f  ",sub[j * sub_region_x_siz + i]);
         }
         printf("\n");
      }

   }


   free(arr);
   free(sub);
   
   return 0;
}



float *sub_region(
                 float *in_fld    ,
                 int    in_fld_nx ,
                 int    in_fld_ny ,
                 int    in_sub_nx ,
                 int    in_sub_ny ,
                 int    in_sub_num
                 )
{
// function that sub-sets a specified size of an input array
// inputs  :
//  1. *in_fld     : 2d field array                              [float* ]
//  2. in_fld_nx   : size of x dimension of the 2d field array   [integer]
//  3. in_fld_ny   : size of y dimension of the 2d field array   [integer]
//  4. in_sub_nx   : size of x dimension of the sub-set array    [integer]
//  5. in_sub_ny   : size of y dimension of the sub-set array    [integer]
//  6. in_sub_num  : number of sub-set array                     [integer]
//
// outputs :
//  1. out_arr     : sub-set array                               [float* ]

   int   i,j;
   int   x_idx_siz   =  in_fld_nx/in_sub_nx  ,
         y_idx_siz   =  in_fld_ny/in_sub_ny  ,
         y_stride    =  in_fld_ny * in_sub_ny,
         *lt_idxs    =  malloc(sizeof(int) * x_idx_siz * y_idx_siz);

   float *out_arr    =  malloc(sizeof(float) * in_sub_nx * in_sub_ny);

   printf("\ny stride : %d\n",y_stride);
   printf("idxs: ");

   // calculating left top indexes for the sub-set arrays (x-direction)
   for (j=0;j<y_idx_siz;j++)
      for (i=0;i<x_idx_siz;i++)
      {
         lt_idxs[j * x_idx_siz + i]  = j * y_stride + i * in_sub_nx; 
         printf("%d ",j * y_stride + i * in_sub_nx);
      }

   // sub-setting array
   for (j=0;j<in_sub_ny;j++)
      for (i=0;i<in_sub_nx;i++)
      {
         out_arr[j * in_sub_nx + i] = in_fld[lt_idxs[in_sub_num] + j * in_fld_nx + i];
      }


   return out_arr;
   free(out_arr);
   free(lt_idxs);
   free(in_fld);
}
```

Here I created `sub` and `free` it at the end of the main code. And in the main code I've got the sub-region output from the function `sub_region`. Like my first question, I tried to free the pointer objects inside the function `sub_region` as I allocated a memory for the `out_arr`.

Comment: It really depends on what is expected of that pointer passed in parameter after the function is called. Usual good practice is whoever allocated memory is responsible for freeing it, but that's not always the most favorable thing to do depending on your specific goal (performance, maintability, etc).
Also, in your example, the memory is NOT freed, since the call is never reached after `return`.

Comment: Neither of your arrays in your example get freed, because you've already returned. Code after the return is not executed. With that said, you should not be freeing `input_array`, because you didn't allocate it in `some_func` and don't know what will be done with it after your function exits. Even if you do right now, you don't know for sure what the function might be used for in future code.

Comment: Apart from the answer being basically "No, at least not like that." (see nice answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70597699/7733418 ), answering your question would need more info on the context of how your function is called. A [mre] might help. But relevant quotes from the interface design documentation would be better. Your question probably is not based on such a design, which makes it too abstract, too theoretical. I choose to use the close-vote reason "needs focus" to reflect that.

Comment: "Here I created sub and free it at the end of the main code." Hmm, I'd call that the start of main()... not end...

Comment: Are you asking about your specific code or about the general principle?

Comment: In general and also for the specific example above (edited question).

Comment: With every dynamic allocation comes an obligation to free, which must be fulfilled exactly once.  The function that performs the allocation can pass that on to another that it calls or back to its own caller, or even associate it with a data structure, but all functions involved must be clear about the transfer of responsibility.  A pointer can be passed or returned without transferring an obligation to free, and often that is more appropriate, but again, all functions involved must agree.

Answer (score 4):

This code is bad in several levels:

1. Your `free` statements are after the `return` statements, so they are not called anyway
2. Freeing the `input_array` could be ok, as long as it is well understood by the caller that this is what the function does. But I don't think it is a good practice.
3. Freeing the `output_array` is a big mistake! It means that you return a pointer to a memory section that can be re-allocated at any time.
   It will be indeterministic and a nightmare to debug.

Comment: So then it is not required to `free` the `output_array` inside the function? If so, what happens to the memory that played a role in the function?

Comment: It is up for the caller to free the memory. And it should be clear and well documented. Another (maybe better) option is to let the caller allocate the memory and pass it to the function

Answer (score 2):

I answer to provide a different angle in addition to the existing answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70597699/7733418
which I basically agree with.

I will make a few assumptions in order to harvest as much meaningful concepts and code from the question as possible.

Assumption 1:
Your code implies that freeing the input array does make sense.
This in turn means that your interface design requires that and relies on the input array being dynamically allocated elsewhere before calling the shown function and that it is guaranteed to NOT be accessed in any way afterwards. Basically the caller knows that the input array will be freed.

Assumption 2:
Your code implies that you are aware that any malloced memory should be freed.
Which is true. (Though arguably relying on certain allocations to be freed at termination is possible. I just don't like it...)

Assumption 3:
The shown code (spefically the attempt to free after the return) demonstrates that you are aware that the freeing should not be done before the contained data has been used.
Obviously true.

So these things are not really wrong in your code.
The recommendable goals are however not achieved the way you implemented it.
I refer to the other answer which explains it. Just to summarize: Not AFTER return.

A meaningful interface design would hence have to require either of these two options

- require the caller to free the allocated output array (after using it) and relinquish ownership of the allocated input array; for a `free` for the input array inside the function
- require the caller to free the allocated output array (after using it) and free the input array, if no free is done for the input array inside the function

Comment: I wrote this answer basically before the question edit, though I posted it afterwards. It is not really aware of the added code. But a quick scan has shown nothing added which really contradicts my answer, just some parts a little redundant. Let me know if I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of API design, it is *usually* considered poor form to mix resource creation/destruction (e.g. opening/closing files, allocationg/deallocating memory), with other unrelated tasks.

Think about this from how the code looks at the call site.  Would you think this is clear about when regions are deallocated?

```
float* r1 = alloc_region(arg, arg, arg);
float* r2 = sub_region(r1, arg, arg, arg);
free(r2);
```

What if the caller wants to create multiple sub-regions from one region?

```
float* r1 = alloc_region();
float* r2 = sub_region(r1);
float* r3 = sub_region(r1);  /* bad: r1 was free'd above! */
```

So in this case I suggest making the caller free the original region, as this is more flexible and clear.

```
float* r1 = alloc_region();
float* r2 = sub_region(r1);
float* r3 = sub_region(r1);
free(r1);
free(r2);
free(r3);
```